# port binding, load-balancer and scale-out architecture with embedded-tomcat and apache http server

Tags: tomcat, load-balancing, embedded-tomcat-7, 12factor, microservices

The [12-factor app](http://12factor.net) suggests to use [port-binding](http://12factor.net/port-binding) so that the app is completely self-contained. We can use embedded tomcat or jetty to achieve this but I was wondering what how scaling out is handled in this scenario.

**Setup**

Currently I have services exposed using embedded tomcat. I can use Apache HTTP server for load-balancing.

**Question**

How to dynamically add new services to scale-out in this scenario? I ask because adding new service means that I also need to add it as part of the EXISTING cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you put in front of the app, in the past I've used nginx and HA Proxy, and the config files for those services need to be adjusted to be aware of the additional instances you're now running. Hopefully that's automated as part of the same process that created those new instances.

Comment: Why nginx amd ha proxy both?

Comment: I should have been clearer, I've used both... but not at the same time. One or the other for a given setup.